# How can I force a JavaScript library to load in the <head> of a page?

Tags: 8, javascript

How do I force a JavaScript library to load in the < head > in Drupal 8?

Here's my themename.libraries.yml file:

```
zaccordion:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/jquery.zaccordion.js: { header: true }
    js/jquery.zaccordion.min.js: { header: true }
    js/zaccordionUsage.js: { header: true }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

It still loads in the footer however.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`header: true` needs to go under your js declaration, not within each file.

See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme

> By default, all JS assets are now loaded in the footer. Being loaded
>   in the header is now an opt-in choice, that is only necessary for
>   critical UI elements that cannot be shown unless their corresponding
>   JS has already run.

```
js-header:
  header: true
  js:
    header.js: {}

js-footer:
  js:
    footer.js: {}
```

> You have to set the new header property on asset library definitions
>   to true, to indicate that the JavaScript assets in that asset library
>   are in the critical path, and should therefore be loaded from the
>   header. Note that any dependencies — direct and indirect — of asset
>   libraries marked as being in the critical path are also automatically
>   loaded from the header, so you don't need to worry about dependencies
>   being unavailable.