# unable to force JS library to HEAD

Tags: theming

I've read the main docs about this but find it lacking context. This did better job of explaining and it seems it should work. [How to force a JavaScript library to load in the <head> of a Drupal 8 page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213364/how-to-force-a-javascript-library-to-load-in-the-head-of-a-drupal-8-page) 
EVERY attempt I try returns

```
A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value
```

Searching for this, I've attempted to enclose the include line in single quotes, without, but all within context of attempting 
js-header

Since this YML, I'm making sure we're using two spaces for indentation and nothing else. What am I overlooking here? This is a snippet of mytheme.libraries.yml

```
  flexslider:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      includes/flexslider/css/flexslider.css: {}
  js:
    includes/flexslider/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery

fontawesome:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      includes/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css: {}

global-styling:
  version: 1.3.2
  css:
    theme:
      includes/mapquest/css/mapquest.css: {}
  js-header:
    header: true
      js:
        includes/mapquest/js/mapquest.js: {}
```

This is portion of mytheme.info.yml that applies:

```
  #Libraries
  libraries:
  - mytheme/bootstrap
  - mytheme/flexslider
  - mytheme/fontawesome
  - mytheme/global-components
  - mytheme/global-styling
```

Comment: Is the indentation of the libraries section correct? You can also run YAML files through a linter to double check them, and most IDEs or editors like VSCode offer yaml linter plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've indented too far. The line following `header: true` is directly beneath it in the example you linked to.

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.3.2
  css:
    theme:
      includes/mapquest/css/mapquest.css: {}
js-header:
  header: true
  js:
    includes/mapquest/js/mapquest.js: {}
```

Comment: Actually you mean he indented the `js:` line too far, that's underneath `header: true`

Comment: You're right - added the code snippet to make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: Excellent. Quote error gone! Still not loading this JS, despite others in same /includes are loading. Are we certain this is correct syntax? CSS loads. Whenever js-header is used, it's not loaded or 'Quote' error.

Comment: Tested it on a local site and it looks like the `header: true` is a property of the library itself. See my revised code snippet.

Comment: Yes it is. To achieve the same behavior as intended by the OP, you should as final edit add the `js-header` library to the dependencies of the `global-styling` library.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Still not loading the JS. Zero spaces for 'js-header', two each for 'header:', 'js:', four for 'includes ...', right? Of course, drush cr after every save..

Comment: You added it as a library under `libraries:` in the theme info yml?

Comment: @sam452 what the revised libraries definition of B. Schroeder does, is defining an entirely new library named `js-header` that will add it's files to the page headers. What you will have to do to making it work is either adding this new library to the dependencies of the `global-styling` library, or as suggested by Kevin to the `libraries` section of your theme's `*.info.yml`.

Comment: Yes, thanks to all! Added '- mytheme/js-header' to mytheme.info.yml. Add the info.yml and I'll accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any root level declaration in your libraries.yml file of your theme need to be added via `#attached` in preprocess hooks, `{{ attach ...}}` in a Twig file, or globally by adding it to the theme info yaml:

```
  #Libraries
  libraries:
    - mytheme/bootstrap
    - mytheme/flexslider
    - mytheme/fontawesome
    - mytheme/global-components
    - mytheme/global-styling
    - mytheme/js-header
```

I'd also advise giving it a better name than 'js-header'.