# How to load a dependency in the <head> in drupal 9?

Tags: javascript

I have followed the official [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml), but it doesn't work

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
    js/custom.js: {}
    
  css:
    component:
      css/style.css: {weight: 50}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
    - core/popperjs
    - my_theme/fontawesome


fontawesome:
  js-header:
    header: true
    js:
      //kit.fontawesome.com/12345678.js: {}
```

This gives me error:

> Drupal\Core\Asset\Exception\IncompleteLibraryDefinitionException: Incomplete library definition for definition 'fontawesome' in extension 'my_theme' in Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->buildByExtension() (line 131 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryParser.php).

Please note that I wanna keep my js file in the `dependencies`, I don't want to do the following:

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  js-header:
    header: true
      js: 
        //kit.fontawesome.com/1234556.js: {}
```

Comment: The code you showed does not match the error. You're receiving an error regarding a library named `fontawesome`, declared in `*.libraries.yml`, and you don't have a library with that name in the code you showed us. So something's not matching up.

Comment: @Jaypan Sorry mate, I have fixed the code in the question. I was playing around with pro versions.

Comment: Mario has given you a working answer, but I would question, why do you need this in the head? If it's just to ensure that it loads ahead of your own script, you can/should just set your `fontawesome` library as a dependency of the library that will depend upon it. Dependencies always load first, and as pages usually load better/faster with scripts at the end of the page, it would be better to not have it in the header. That said, if there is a specific requirement to have `fontawesome` load in the header specifically, Mario's solution is the way to go.

Comment: The Font Awesome Kits documentation ( https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/use-kit ) indeed states to place their code into the head of a site. Never used it myself, so I have no clue whether it's really required in a page head for all its features to work. The answer given intends to teach more about YAML anyway. ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a JavaScript library to load in the <head> of a Drupal 8 page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213364/how-to-force-a-javascript-library-to-load-in-the-head-of-a-drupal-8-page)

Comment: @leymannx that does not answer my question, I used exactly what that answer said and it didn't work.

Comment: @jaypan I assume fontawesome loads the font/css files via js, If I have it in the footer, I think my cssomloaded might fire before fontawesome downloads, causing FOUC.

Comment: Well, looking at your question you did not use it like the other answer said.

Comment: @leymannx I disagree.

Comment: @leymannx I had to rollback your edit, because I want to focus on only dependencies. Libraries in general might not be a dependency and doesn't have to fall under `dependencies:` yaml attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`js-header` is not a valid libraries configuration key. If you read the [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml#s-asset-loading-order) closely, you will find, that it has been used as library name (first level of the yml file) for the example given.

Instead, you'll have to define your fontawesome library this way:

```
fontawesome:
  header: true
  js:
    //kit.fontawesome.com/12345678.js: { external: true }
```

[YAML](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/configuration-file-coding-standards) (in Drupal just *.yml) files are used to describe data structures (configuration). They use indentations for nested scopes. So it is very important that you don't add indentations where they aren't needed and provide configuration keys at the level where they are expected by Drupal. That is, at the second level of a library definition (first indentation), `version`, `js`, `css`, `dependencies` and `header` are allowed only, each of which has its own expected sub structure.

Either `js` or `css` MUST exist with at least one entry for a library. The error you have seen occurs, if you define a library without any `js` or `css` configuration keys.